# How much is a total market dividend yield expected to drop in a bad year?

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-markets, dividends

Let's take a total US market ETF like VTI. Its dividend yield is about 2%. How much will it drop on a bad year, when its composing stocks are mostly down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's true that some companies may cut their dividend if a bad year pushes them over the edge, overall dividend yield will increase in a bad year because of share price  decline.

Here's the yield for the SPY for the past 15 years.  As you can see, its yield dramatically increased in 2008 when the market dropped ~39%.

```
Date            Yield

Dec 31, 2019    1.81% estimate

Dec 31, 2018    2.09%

Dec 31, 2017    1.84%

Dec 31, 2016    2.03%

Dec 31, 2015    2.11%

Dec 31, 2014    1.92%

Dec 31, 2013    1.94%

Dec 31, 2012    2.20%

Dec 31, 2011    2.13%

Dec 31, 2010    1.83%

Dec 31, 2009    2.02%

Dec 31, 2008    3.23% <---

Dec 31, 2007    1.87%

Dec 31, 2006    1.76%

Dec 31, 2005    1.76%
```

Comment: Very interesting. So overall, dividend yield isn't very sensitive to stock price movements, it seems.

Comment: Dividend yield for a large ETF would not be very sensitive to normal stock price movements.  For an individual stock, the variance would be higher.

Comment: I think both the question and the answer are very misleading (in that you're not asking what you want to know). If a company you own doesn't adjust their dividend while the stock price falls 50%, your dividend yield just doubled. Why does that matter, though ? It only matters if you're buying shares for the new price. In other words: If the stock price drops 50% but the dividend drops 25% you're getting a far better dividend yield, but it's less money than it was before.

Comment: @xyious - Given that I understood what the OP asked  and that the OP understood what I answered, then why did the OP award me 'favorite answer' if we  were misleading each other?

Comment: @BobBaerker You answered the question that was asked. My issue is that it's the wrong question. Assume you invested $100k into the stock market, then the market drops 50%, the dividend yield goes up 25%.... Do you care about the current yield ? No. You care about whether or not the dividend went up or down, you don't care what the yield comes out to. So you had 2% the past year, which was $2k, now you have 2.5% which is $1.25k.

Comment: @xyious - You  think that the right question is what you think the question should have been when the OP was seeking an answer to what he was questioning.  He asked.  I answered.  If he wanted more info or clarification, he would, could and should  have posed a  question in a comment.  He didn't.  Ya think it's time to move on?